# Returning dictionary representation of object when class attributes are private (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I am trying to generate a dictionary from an object in Python. I have used `object.__dict__` which works when the class attributes are not set to private. However when I set the attributes to private, the dictionary keys change from `'attribute'` to `'_ClassName__attribute'`

I'm just wondering if there's a built in function to keep the attribute name as just `'length'` (to give an example), or if I would have to do something else.

```
class Rectangle():
    def __init__(self,length,breadth):
        self.__length = length
        self.__breadth = breadth

    def get_length(self):
        return self.__length

    def get_breadth(self):
        return self.__breadth

r = Rectangle(2,4)
print(r.__dict__)
```

Output:

```
{'_Rectangle__length': 2, '_Rectangle__breadth': 4}
```

Desired Output:

```
{'length': 2, 'breadth': 4}
```

EDIT: Should note that my code is a bit more complex than this, and due to inheritance, some of my dictionaries may look something like this:

```
{'_Rectangle__length' : 2, '_Circle__radius' : 5, '_Square__height' : 9}
```

As such, if there is no built-in function to do what I'm looking for simply, I may need to to remove everything up to and including `__` for all keys. I've already tried this, but had issues with not being able to update a dictionary during iteration. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Just to note, they aren't *private*. They are just mangled to avoid being accidentally shadowed by attributes in a child class. I would strongly recommend against using `__`-prefixed attribute names unless you have a good reason to do so; don't just default to using them because private attributes are the norm in languages that have visibility modifiers.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't be using `__dict__` directly outside of an instance method, and you try to avoid doing so without good reason *inside* a method as well.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a reason why I shouldn't be using it? The reason for doing so is in my real code I'm saving all attribute values down to a CSV for each object created using DictWriter. Converting to a dictionary this way was therefore convenient. And yes I may just remove the `__` ultimately.

Comment: It's an implementation detail, not really part of your class's interface. In fact, if you use the `__slots__` class attribute, your instances *won't* have a `__dict__` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Pythonic design would be

```
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, length, breadth):
        self._length = length
        self._breadth = breadth

    @property
    def length(self):
        return self._length

    @property
    def breadth(self):
        return self._breadth

    def to_dict(self):
        return {'length': self._length, 'breadth': self._breadth}

r = Rectangle(2, 4)
print(r.to_dict())
```

Use `_`-prefixed names to indicate attributes that should not be used directly, and use `property` to provide read-only access to such attributes. Define a method that produces the desired `dict` *explicitly*, rather than trying to reuse `__dict__` directly.

Comment: Perfect thank you! I gave this a go and it works perfect. I don't know why I didn't think of this.